# JavaFX Bind layoutY : A bound value cannot be set

Tags: java, layout, javafx, binding

This question is not related to the others because I am no trying to set layoutY value with a bound value already set.

So, I dont have any `loginButton.setLayoutY();` applied.

However if I set `loginButton.layoutYProperty().bind(anchorPane.prefHeightProperty());` then I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Button.layoutY : A bound value cannot be set.
```

If I set `loginButton.setManaged(false);` it doesnt give an exception, however the button is not visible anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All layout panes, such as `AnchorPane`, manage the layout of their managed child nodes according to configuration you apply to the pane and the children. They do this by setting the `layoutX` and `layoutY` properties. In other words, the anchor pane itself is calling `loginButton.setLayoutY(...)`, resulting in the exception you see if you bind the `layoutY` property.

If you call `setManaged(false)`, then the anchor pane will not attempt to position or resize the `loginButton`, and you don't get the exception. Note that if the anchor pane is sized to its preferred size, then your binding will position the top of the login button (its `layoutY` property) at the height of the anchor pane, i.e. the very bottom of the anchor pane, and the button will be outside the anchor pane's bounds. Hence it will not be visible. You will also need to explicitly size the button, using `loginButton.resize(...)`.

The bottom line is that you should not use bindings to perform layout. Use the existing layout panes to manage the layout (position and size) of your nodes. The tutorial has an [overview of the layout panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102). If you really can't find a combination of layout panes and settings on them that gives you the desired layout (which is highly unlikely), the way to define a custom layout is to subclass `Pane` and implement your own `layoutChildren()` method. To use this approach, you could start by looking at how the existing panes are [implemented](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/graphics/src/main/java/javafx/scene/layout).

If you want the button to be at the bottom of the pane, just tell the anchor pane to position it there. Replace the binding with

```
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(loginButton, 0.0);
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, I got it about AnchorPane, but I still dont understand about setManaged(false), I set any value to layoutY and layoutX, the buttom dont appear in the layout.

Comment: @Marckaraujo If you set `managed` to `false`, it's probably not setting the size of the button either. Try also calling `resize()`. But you really shouldn't be doing things this way in the first place: use the layout panes the way they are intended to be used.

Comment: @Marckaraujo Added mention of size to the answer.

Comment: yes, the best for me was to change `AnchorPane` to `Pane`, so it  will not set layoutY property and dont need to `setManaged(false)`. Thanks

Comment: after I set `loginButton.resize(200.00, 50.0);`, with the `setManaged(false)` applied too, the bindLayoutX dont work, why this?